# How to count occurrences of two elements in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, count

I have an entry array with task list fields (as per below) and the fields `important` and `urgent` are **Strings** which I used to have four combinations of status (Important & Urgent, Important & None, None & Urgent and None & None). so I would like to count how many of each combination I have in total.

```swift
entry = [ 
    TaskList(
        id: isPlus,
        isComplete: displayComplete,
        dateAdded: displayAdded!,
        name: displayName!,
        secondaryCategory: displayCategory!,
        important: displayImportance!,       //String
        urgent: displayUrgency!              //String
    ),

    TaskList(...)
]
```

> i.e.:
> `important & urgent` = 3, `important & none` = 2,
>      `none & urgent` = 0,      `none & none` = 4

Comment: This does not seem like it’s enough information to solve here. Also, all of that force unwrapping is likely to be dangerous. And, even if it isn’t, there’s likely a better pattern you could be using (look at “if let”, for example)

Comment: What have you tried and where do you got stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How will could iterate over Sequence & get an occurrence of data.

```swift
var greetingArr = Array("Hello, playground")
var occurrences = Dictionary(greetingArr.map{($0, 1)}) { i, j in i + 1 }
             //or Dictionary(greetingArr.map{($0, 1)}) { $0 + $1 }
             //or Dictionary(greetingArr.map{($0, 1)}, uniquingKeysWith: +)

// occurrences ⬻ ["e": 1, "l": 3, "o": 2, "n": 1, "a": 1, ",": 1, "y": 1 
//                 " ": 1, "d": 1, "H": 1, "u": 1, "p": 1, "r": 1, "g": 1]
```

In this case, an iterator is your `entry` Array & wants to find an occurrence of a particular combination of its two properties (`important` & `urgent`).
If those property is String type:

```swift
var dict = Dictionary(entry.map{($0.important + "-" + $0.urgent, 1)}) { $0 + $1 }
```

If there is a function that gives Int, From those two properties.

> `important,urgent ⤖ 3`, `important,none ⤖ 2`, `none,urgent ⤖ 0` & `none,none ⤖ 4`

then you can map `entry.map{($0.intFromTwoProperties, 1)}` instead of the previous mapping,
but that will give you an occurrence dictionary with that Int key.